# VS 2017 Multi Edit mode based on custom keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Does Visual Studio 2017 have support for multi line editing (like Sublime and VS Code )? I had this terrible "Mix Edit" extension for VS 2015 that worked some of the time, but since upgrading, I need to have multiple cursors for changing many lines at a time, etc.

[MultiEditMode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MultiEditMode) requires mouse action and I rarely touch my mouse.

I need to be able to use `Control + D` to select the next instance of the highlighted variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of what made this confusing was that Visual Studio menus and docs refer to Cursors as "Carets".

I found this: 
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4408859-native-multi-editing-multiple-cursors-and-selecti?category_id=35066&page=2&per_page=20

... which says you can use `Shift+Atl+,` and `Shift+Alt+,` So that's the first half.

The second half of this involved going to Tools > Customize > Keyboard... then I mapped:

"Insert Next Matching Caret" to `Control+D`
"Insert Carets at All Matching" to `Alt+F3`

Now I can highlight just like Sublime, VSCode, etc.